# MAC OS X 10.8.4 Login Stuck on password - Restart logind service?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a remote MAC that is stuck on the login screen for the local user. The login screen is stuck right after the password was entered. I can login to the remote MAC with ssh and run commands. This MAC is hosting a database for other users so I would rather not restart it if possible.

Is there a command I can run that would restart the core service logind so that I do not have to restart the computer?

If the answer is no, can I restart the computer using sudo shutdown -r now remotely over ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could run `killall loginwindow` to restart the login window process which should stop the authentication attempt.

And yes, `sudo shutdown -r now` should force the remote Mac to reboot immediately.

Comment: `killall loginwindow` will log out *any* user already logged in

Comment: After running the killall command, how would I restart the process, or does that happen automatically?

Comment: @MichaelA. I believe the process will restart automatically since it's one of the main processes.  This is the case when you run killall on Dock, Finder, etc..

Comment: The command worked to kill the process but it did not release the console. I ended up restarting the computer. Restarting remotely also hung so I had to hold down the power button. I was able to shutdown the database program remotely so I was happy about that. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Log in as an admin user via SSH and run

```
ps aux | grep -i loginwindow
```

Look for the PID of the login process of the local user and then do

```
sudo kill -9 <PID of user's loginwindow process>
```

to terminate it.